# Using INDIRECT to sum cells in another spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

In my worksheet titled “Data!” I have the following successful formula:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(CHAR(64+MATCH(E3,A3:N3,0))&MATCH($B165,$A$1:$A$900,0)&":"&(CHAR(64+MATCH(E3,A3:N3,0))&MATCH($B165,$A$1:$A$900,0)+$O$2-1)))
```

Please don't bother with the details, as my problem is related to referencing another spreadsheet, as explained below. But in sum, the above formula works as intended by summing cells E124 to E133. In cell E3 I have the desired column name.  In B165 I have the desired year.

I need the formula to be in a different worksheet. So, in my second worksheet I’ve written:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("Data!"&(CHAR(64+MATCH(Data!E3,Data!A3:N3,0))&MATCH($O3,Data!A1:A900,0)&":"&"Data!"&(CHAR(64+MATCH(Data!E3,Data!A3:N3,0)&MATCH($O$3,Data!A1:A900,0)))))
```

However, this brings me a #VALUE error.

When I break the formula into two parts it works.

That is, this works:
    CHAR(64+MATCH(Data!E3,Data!A3:N3,0))&MATCH($O3,Data!A1:A900,0)

And this works:
    (CHAR(64+MATCH(Data!E3,Data!A3:N3,0)&MATCH($O$3,Data!A1:A900,0)))

But when I combine the two it breaks down. I suppose that the error has to do with the parts bolded below where I reference my initial worksheet.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(**"Data!"**&(CHAR(64+MATCH(Data!E3,Data!A3:N3,0))&MATCH($O3,Data!A1:A900,0)&":"**&"Data!"**&(CHAR(64+MATCH(Data!E3,Data!A3:N3,0)&MATCH($O$3,Data!A1:A900,0))))))
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: check out the number of parantheses , they are not equal.

Comment: i think you need to remove the second &"Data!" because the resulting formula needs to be like Data!A3:N3 not Data!A3:Data!N3

Comment: @AHC, the parenthesis seems ok when I break the formula into two. It's just when I add "Data!" that the formula stops working. Thanks though.

Comment: @Siphor , you're right that Data!A3:N3 is how we usually see this formula, but Data!A3:Data!N3 should actually bring you the same answer (it's just a longer way of writing it out). I tried editing it as you suggested with no luck. Thanks though. Any other ideas?

Comment: did you test the formula on the "Data" sheet?

Comment: also you can simplify the formula with the address function: =SUM(INDIRECT("Data!"&ADDRESS(MATCH($O3,Data!A1:A900,0),MATCH(Data!E3,Data!A3:N3,0))&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH($O$3,Data!A1:A900,0),MATCH(Data!E3,Data!A3:N3,0))))

Comment: @Siphor the first formula in my above post works in the "Data" sheet but the last formula in my post above doesn't work anywhere (despite the two components that I mention above working). I must be referencing the "Data" sheet incorrectly.

Comment: @Siphor I need to think about that some more, but I don't think it'll work. Thing is, I need Excel to find a column letter based on the results of a column name found in a dropdown menu -- hence the (CHAR(64+...jazz.

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATED*** 
i updated my formula, and this works perfect now.

Here is the corrected version of your formula:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("Data!"&(CHAR(64+MATCH(Data!E3,Data!A3:N3,0))&MATCH($G3,Data!A1:A900,0)&":"&CHAR(64+MATCH(Data!E3,Data!A3:N3,0))&(MATCH($G$3,Data!A1:A900,0)+Data!$O$2-1))))
```

i think this is gonna work.

Comment: I tried it and it says I'm missing a parenthesis. Adding one brought me back to #VALUE. Thanks again for looking into this though. Any other ideas?

Comment: could you please share a copy of your worksheet? via dropbox/googledrive/onedrive? it will help alot.

Answer (score 0):

The correct formula is:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("Data!"&(CHAR(64+MATCH(Data!E3,Data!A3:N3,0)))
   &MATCH($O3,Data!A1:A‌​900,0)&":"&CHAR(64+MATCH(Data!E3,Data!A3:N3,0))
   &MATCH($O$3,Data!A1:A900,0)+Data!$‌​O$2-1))
```

Comment: i updated my formula, with minor changes and now it works for me;